# Traversing in xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've never used xpath before and it's driving me batty. I have the following XML:

```
<entry>
 <updated>2018-02-20</updated>
  <api:related>
   <api:object>
    <api:ever-approved>true</api:ever-approved>
    <api:reporting-date-1>2017-12-31</api:reporting-date-1>
    <api:repository-items>
     <api:repository-item repository-id="1">
      <api:public-url>http://url.com</api:public-url>
      <api:content-file-count>1</api:content-file-count>
      <api:licence-file-count>1</api:licence-file-count>
      <api:status>accepted</api:status>
     </api:repository-item>
    </api:repository-items>
    <api:all-labels type="keyword-list">
     <api:keywords>
      <api:keyword>Africa</api:keyword>
      <api:keyword>Economy</api:keyword>
     </api:keywords>
    </api:all-labels>
  </api:object>
</api:related>
```

...which repeats in that structure. I just need to write some PHP to check whether "api:repository-items" - or any child node within it - exists for each entry. I can do this successfully for:

- api:ever-approved
- api:reporting-date-1
- first api:keyword

by doing variations of:

```
foreach ( $this->xml->xpath( 'api:related/api:object/api:all-labels/api:keywords/api:keyword[1]' ) as $field ) {
        $this->properties['xxx'] = $field;
            }

 if ( isset( $this->properties['xxx'] ) ){
            return $this->properties['xxx'];
        } else {
            return 'nada';
        }
```

And that works fine. However, I cannot traverse to anything in the repository-items - I only get 'nada'.

I have tried:

- 'api:related/api:object/api:repository-items/api:repository-item/api:status'
- 'api:related/api:object/api:repository-items/api:repository-item/api:content-file-count'
- 'api:related/api:object/api:repository-items/api:repository-item'
- 'api:related/api:object/api:repository-items'
- 'api:related/api:object//api:status'

What am I doing wrong - and any other suggestions?! Thanks!

Comment: You haven't shown any namespace bindings for the "api" prefix. Since incorrect namespace bindings are a common source of XPath problems, this means we can't verify that you got this right.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the XML correctly, this is the correct XPATH:

```
'//entry//api:repository-items'
```

The `//entry` searches for the relative path to nodes called `entry` in the XML, while `//api:repository-items` searches for the relative path on nodes called `api:repository-items` that are nested on the nodes found on `//entry`.

I **strongly** recommend reading the [w3schools XPATH guide](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). It's a great guide containing all the information you should need about XPATHs with some graphic examples, and it's not very long.

Comment: Thanks - but you've missed the point slightly - I've already accounted for the entry node within $this: as I say, the path "api:related/api:object/api:all-labels/api:keywords/api:keyword[1]" works perfectly. I'm trying to understand why that WOULD, but "api:related/api:object/api:repository-items/api:repository-item/api:content-file-count" - and indeed "//api:repository-items" wouldn't. (Oh - and I have indeed already read the w3schools XPATH guide - it's great, but hasn't helped me here!)

Comment: I misinterpreted the question indeed, sorry.

Still, the xpath isn't wrong, and if your XML structure is like that across the document those xpath's you provided on 'what i've tried' section should also work fine. I guess that the problem is on how you're using the xpath result on your PHP code?
Unfortunately I can't help you with that right now, I'll try to edit this answer later.

Comment: Thanks Lucas - that's reassuring... I think the actual problem lies with the XML I've been given.